# Maven create python conda virtual environment

Tags: python, maven, conda

I want to create a maven build file that needs to run unit tests of a python solution.

The solution has its python packages so they need to be pip installed in a conda virtual environment.

Is there a way to create a conda virtual environment using maven?

Comment: You can probably get away with configuring maven to run a command on your system using something like [this](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html)

Comment: Can you please tell me more on what needs to be in the command?